# Modifying wrapper python print to return type

Tags: python, wrapper

All I get from this code is that, print in python is a wrapper function of `write` method of `stdout` so if I give it a return type it must return that as well, right? Then why can't I do that?

```
import sys
class CustomPrint():
    def __init__(self):
        self.old_stdout=sys.stdout

    def write(self, text):
        text = text.rstrip()
        if len(text) == 0: return
        self.old_stdout.write('custom Print--->' + text + '\n')
        return text
sys.stdout=CustomPrint()
print "ab" //works
a=print "ab" //error! but why?
```

Answer (score 4):

In python2.x, `print` is a *statement*.  So, `a = print "ab"` is illegal syntax.  Try just `print "ab"`.

In python3, `print` is a *function* -- So you'd write:  `a = print("ab")`.  Note that starting at python2.6, you can get access to python3's `print` function via `from __future__ import print_function`.

Ultimately, what you want is something like:

```
#Need this to use `print` as a function name.
from __future__ import print_function
import sys   

class CustomPrint(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
    def write(self,text):
        text = text.rstrip()
        if text:
            self._stdout.write('custom Print--->{0}\n'.format(text))
            return text
    __call__ = write

print = CustomPrint()

a = print("ab")
```

Comment: `a = print("ab")` would not help, since `print` always returns `None`. OP should use a custom function for that.

Comment: @bereal -- Sure, `a` would be `None`, but the program would execute and write stuff to `sys.stdout` (which is what I think OP wanted).  I'm not exactly sure what OP expects `a` to be here ...

Comment: from `return text` in `write` I'd assume that he wants `"ab"`.

Comment: @bereal -- Yeah, I saw that after I commented.  I updated with a version that I *think* should work ... Though I haven't tested it yet...

Comment: It's `__future__`, not `__future`, I think.

Comment: @Thomas -- It certainly is . . . Thanks.